# How do I add a prefix to the right hand side of a Formula using update?

Tags: r, formula

Say I have a list of `Formula`'s:

```
library(Formula)
models <- list(y ~ x1, y ~ x2, y ~ x3)
models <- lapply(models, as.Formula)
```

And say I want to update them to be `y ~ 1 | x1 | 1`, `y ~ 1 | x2 | 1`, and `y ~ 1 | x3 | 1` (for example, to work with `mnlogit`).  If I use `update` with `lapply`, I can add the `| 1` to the end:

```
lapply(models, update, . ~ . | 1)  # Works as expected
# [[1]]
# y ~ x1 | 1
# 
# [[2]]
# y ~ x2 | 1
#
# [[3]]
# y ~ x3 | 1
```

But I can't add the `1 |` to the beginning:

```
lapply(models, update, . ~ 1 | . | 1)  # Fails -- why is the dot not replaced?
# [[1]]
# y ~ 1 | . | 1
#
# [[2]]
# y ~ 1 | . | 1
#
# [[3]]
# y ~ 1 | . | 1
```

Does anyone know why this is, or how to fix it (other than fixing each of the models one by one, of course)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the main question: *How can you set up the formulas*?

I would recommend to first add the two additional intercept parts and then re-order the right-hand side:

```
f <- y ~ x2
ff <- update(Formula(f), . ~ . | 1 | 1)
formula(ff, rhs = c(2, 1, 3))
## y ~ 1 | x2 | 1
```

And then concerning: *Why does the update only work with the . in the first part?*

You expected that this code returns the same result:

```
f <- y ~ x2
update(Formula(f), . ~ 1 | . | 1)
## y ~ 1 | . | 1
```

But clearly it doesn't. The reason is simple: The `update()` method cycles through all left-hand and right-hand parts. Here, the first right-hand part `x2` gets updated with `1`. The second right-hand part is empty (`f` only has one right-hand side) and hence gets updated to `.`. Analogously, for the third part.

If there is exactly one right-hand side in the original formula, one could have implemented your approach. But with several parts this would have been a mess. E.g.,

```
update(Formula(y ~ x1 | x2 | x3), . ~ . + z1 | 1 | . - x3)
## y ~ x1 + z1 | 1 | 1
```

Comment: Thank you both for showing how this should work, and for explaining what's going on!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I always take advantage of strings when I face a simple problem. This is in base-R:

```
lapply(models, function(x) {
  as.formula(paste( 'y ~ 1 | ', labels(terms(x)) , '| 1')))
}
```

And output is:

```
[[1]]
y ~ 1 | x1 | 1
<environment: 0x000000000a475128>

[[2]]
y ~ 1 | x2 | 1
<environment: 0x00000000003ea848>

[[3]]
y ~ 1 | x3 | 1
<environment: 0x000000000a94e100>
```

All of them formulas as you need them.

If `mnlogit` accepts strings in the formula argument (i.e. converts any formula strings to formula type internally like `lm` does) then you don't even need the `as.formula` bit in the above `lapply`.

Comment: @AchimZeileis I had `library(Formula)` in mind when I typed it but thanks.

Comment: The `Formula` package has been carefully designed to avoid exactly this: string processing. In this particular case, it is probably ok to go through the term labels. But you can easily get cases where string processing is error prone, especially when recovering formula parts. For example in `y ~ x1 | factor(z1 | z2)` you would need to pay attention to correctly process the second `|`. Also the term labels always expand compact interaction notation (e.g., `a * b` would become `a + b + a:b`) etc.

Comment: @AchimZeileis As for all things you need to know how to use a tool. Building a statistical package it wouldn't make sense to use strings, but for interactive use or for straightforward processes it is usually fine.

Comment: Sure. If you know fairly well what structure the inputs have, then using your suggestion is usually fine. However, I wanted to point out that the string route can lead to problems in some situations. We had encountered this in various packages (including our own!) which was one of the motivations to write the `Formula` package to take care of this.

Comment: @AchimZeileis Thanks for the comments :). I am sure then that you must have encountered problems in some situations since you dedicated your time to build a specialized package. I admit that I haven't explored the `Formula` package yet, but having read your comments I ll do so because your points are valid and I should expand my knowledge on this matter. Thanks!